# NodeJS - Autenticação por token?

Tags: node.js

Estou seguindo uns exemplo aqui sobre autentacação em e está funcionando normal, mas eu gostaria de saber se passar o token pela URL seria mesmo a forma correta ou se tem algum método que seja melhor.

Comment: Coloque o exemplo que esta seguindo, por favor.

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens - O exemplo é de um livro, mas está quase igual a este. Só fiquei em dúvida pois ele não usou uma página como exemplo, foi tudo usando um plugin para fazer as requisições.

Comment: Queria dar uma resposta aqui também mas estou com pouco tempo. O passport.js é muito usado e seria bem apropriado aqui também. Se tiver tempo junto uma resposta com exemplos. Falei sobre ele aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86609/129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, pode-se passar o token pela URL mesmo.

Note que no exemplo, é utilizado JWT, que é um padrão para trafegar tokens e dados de sessão entre o cliente e o servidor, reduzindo a necessidade do servidor manter dados de sessão.

Deve-se tomar cuidado apenas em hipótese alguma enviar informações sensíveis ao cliente, especialmente em uma conexão não segura, já que o campo `payload` do JWT pode ser recuperado na íntegra.

Outra opção, além de enviar o token junto a URL, é utilizar um cookie ou um field específico do cabeçalho HTTP, mas em todos os casos, não há ganhos de segurança de um em relação ao outro.

Comment: Opa, amigo, como eu faria para colocar essa informação no cabeçalho http?

Comment: @Liw.S. desculpe não poder ajudar quanto a isso. Programo apenas PHP e Javascript (do lado cliente). Não conheço NodeJs o suficiente (além de ter feito algo com grunt e gulp) para dizer como fazer.

Comment: Tudo bem, farei uma outra pergunta. Obrigado por responder.

Answer (score 0):

Pode setar o token na url, o melhor a se fazer para nao lotar o campo de endereço é usar no header da requisição, essa parte voce vai configurar no front end, use o angularjs, angular.io(angular 2)... frameworks front end sempre tem algo sobre autenticação Json WebToken.

Para o angularjs eu utilizo o satellizer: https://github.com/sahat/satellizer