# Como fazer dois métodos de serialize e deserialize diferentes em node js, com passport?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tenho dois tipos diferentes de usuário na minha aplicação. Consegui fazer o login em um dos dois usuários utilizando o passport com serialize e deserialize.

O problema é quando vou fazer o segundo login, pois não há uma forma de modificar o `passport.serializeUser` e o `passport.deserializeUser` com o id do segundo login e da tabela MYSQL do segundo login também.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id_user);
});


passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id_user = ? ",[id], function(err, rows){
        done(err, rows[0]);
    });
});
```

Eu tenho dúvida em onde eles são chamados, procurei no meu código e não consigo achar. Pra ser sincero, sou novo em node e nunca trabalhei com esses métodos antes, então tá bem confuso pra mim. Se precisar de alguma outra parte do código eu modifico aqui.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui, relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86609/129

Comment: Então, eu dei uma olhada nisso, mas o meu problema é em relação a dois logins de usuários diferentes, entende? Mas obrigado mesmo assim!